# liferay destroys own source code

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I regularly have the problem that some of the liferay dockbar files (liferay source code) are destroyed/removed  when I compile my code. Then I have to copy these files from the liferay source code again to my liferay folder. Does anyone have an idea how to prevent this problem? I'm using the liferay-tomcat bundle with liferay 6.2.ce-ga4.

Comment: Please explain a little bit more: How do you compile your code (IDE, Maven, ...)? Which files are removed exactly?

Comment: See the next comment by Olaf Kock. That's what seems to be happening here. (I am using maven, indeed, but I do not compile with the IDE. The files that are removed are most of the time the dockbar files.)

Comment: @birgit If that is indeed what happened, consider to "accept" the answer or clarify if it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

As there was only a 6.1 GA3, never a GA4, I'm assuming you mean the current version 6.2 GA4.

There's one common problem: Liferay out of the box delivers the notification portlet, which overrides the dockbar's view.jsp. When you do the same, you will lose the original file.

I've [blogged about this problem](https://www.liferay.com/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/overriding-jsps-from-multiple-hooks-promising-the-cure). The article contains (or links to) an ext-plugin that will prevent the deployment of the second hook that overrides a jsp. The article also gives some information on the mechanics - and I suspect that this is exactly what you're running into.
If it is, you'll either have to undeploy the notification portlet or merge your changes into it.

Comment: True, I changed the version. And yes, your explanation seems plausible. But I'm not sure whether I want to dive too deep into liferay. So I think for the time being I will try to live with the situation...

Comment: Well, it's not very deep. You can just merge your change into the notification-portlet and then you're done. If you want to make sure that this doesn't happen again, deploy the ext-plugin as well - it's quite easy: Drop it in Liferay's deploy folder, then restart. Done. In case you're missing a plugin (because it's not starting up) check the logs which will give you a hint on the reason why it's not starting up. I like that better than random deletion of JSPs when overriding them from multiple hooks.

Comment: Hm, I tried to compile your `hookdeploy-ext` project with ant. But you use the build-common-ext.xml, which is not part of your project. Where to find it?

Comment: It's supposed to be compiled from within the ext folder in a plugin-sdk. The plugin sdk has everything you need to build

Comment: I tried Liferay 6.2 GA5, which should have fixed the multiple-hooks-overwriting-jsps-problem. For a while it worked fine, but now I get again the same problem, dockbar jsps not found.

Comment: There's a separate configuration property that you'll have to set for it to work. Should be documented in the LPS issue that is linked from my blog article

Comment: It seems to work now with the line
```hot.deploy.hook.custom.jsp.verification.enabled=true```
in portal-ext.properties

Comment: I thought it worked, but now I add the notifications portlet, I get the same jsp-destruction problems again ;-(

Comment: Version? Configuration (as listed above) active? Or did you try compiling my hookdeploy-ext again? I like my version better as it gives more definitive answers what's going wrong, where the new built-in functionality just refuses to deploy, without any clue what goes wrong.